# How to override a function when isn't at functions.php

Tags: functions, child-theme, pluggable

I am trying to override a function for a theme in the child-theme but I can't get it to work. At `functions.php` on the theme I can see this `require_once` line:

```
require_once("inc/alterna-functions.php");
```

And I want to override a function inside that file. I just copied the original code from `alterna/functions.php` to `alterna-child/functions.php` and made my changes as follow:

```
if (!function_exists('alterna_get_social_list')) :
    function alterna_get_social_list($extra_name = '', $topbar = false, $data = null, $target = '_blank')
    {
        global $alterna_options;

        $str = "";
        $social_list = array(
            array('twitter', 'Twitter'),
            array('twitter_1', 'Twitter #1'), // this is new
            array('twitter_2', 'Twitter #2'), // this is new
            array('twitter_3', 'Twitter #3'), // this is new
            array('twitter_4', 'Twitter #4'), // this is new
            array('facebook', 'Facebook'),
            array('facebook_1', 'Facebook #1'), // this is new
            array('facebook_2', 'Facebook #2'), // this is new
            array('facebook_3', 'Facebook #3'), // this is new
            array('facebook_4', 'Facebook #4'), // this is new
            array('google', 'Google Plus', 'google-plus'),
            array('google_1', 'Google Plus #1', 'google-plus_1'), // this is new
            array('google_2', 'Google Plus #2', 'google-plus_2'), // this is new
            array('google_3', 'Google Plus #3', 'google-plus_3'), // this is new
            array('google_4', 'Google Plus #4', 'google-plus_4'), // this is new
            array('youtube', 'Youtube'),
            array('linkedin', 'Linkedin'),
            array('instagram', 'instagram'),
            array('whatsapp', 'Whatsapp'),
            array('email', 'Email', 'envelope'),
            array('rss', 'Rss')
        );

        if ($data != null) {
            foreach ($social_list as $social_item) {
                if (isset($data['type']) && $data['type'] == $social_item[0]) {
                    if (!isset($data['url'])) {
                        $data['url'] = '#';
                    }
                    if (!isset($data['target'])) {
                        $data['target'] = '_blank';
                    }
                    $str .= '<li class="social"><a  href="' . esc_attr($data['url']) . '" target="' . esc_attr($data['target']) . '"';

                    if (isset($data['tooltip']) && $data['tooltip'] == "yes") {
                        $str .= ' title="' . esc_attr($social_item[1]) . '" class="show-tooltip"';
                        if (isset($data['placement']) && $data['placement'] != "") {
                            $str .= ' data-placement="' . esc_attr($data['placement']) . '"';
                        }
                    }

                    $str .= '><span class="alterna-icon-' . esc_attr($social_item[0]) . '"';

                    if ($data['bg_color'] != "" || $data['color'] != "") {
                        $str .= ' style="';
                        if ($data['bg_color'] != "") {
                            $str .= 'background:' . esc_attr($data['bg_color']) . ';';
                        }
                        if ($data['color'] != "") {
                            $str .= 'color:' . esc_attr($data['color']) . ';';
                        }
                        $str .= '"';
                    }

                    $str .= '><i class="fa fa-' . (isset($social_item[2]) ? esc_attr($social_item[2]) : esc_attr($social_item[0])) . '"></i></span></a></li>';
                }
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($social_list as $social_item) {
                if (penguin_get_options_key('social-' . $social_item[0]) != '') {
                    if (!$topbar) {
                        $str .= '<li class="social"><a title="' . esc_attr($social_item[1]) . '" href="' . esc_attr(penguin_get_options_key('social-' . $social_item[0])) . '" target="' . esc_attr($target) . '" ><span class="alterna-icon-' . esc_attr($social_item[0]) . '"><i class="fa fa-' . (isset($social_item[2]) ? esc_attr($social_item[2]) : esc_attr($social_item[0])) . '"></i></span></a></li>';
                    } else {
                        $str .= '<li class="social"><a href="' . esc_attr(penguin_get_options_key('social-' . $social_item[0])) . '" target="' . esc_attr($target) . '" ><i class="fa fa-' . (isset($social_item[2]) ? esc_attr($social_item[2]) : esc_attr($social_item[0])) . '"></i></a></li>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $str;
    }
endif;
```

But it's not working since I can't see the changes on the theme. What I am doing wrong? Which is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: Is the function actually a method of a class or is there some other wrapping code involved?  Are you hooking to a specific action or how is the function triggered?

Comment: @jdm2112 is a common function and nothing else is wrapping it's code. It's triggered from inside a function called `alterna_get_topbar_content()` where the function `alterna_get_social_list()` is invoked

Comment: Did you copy the `require_once` statement into your child theme's functions.php or copy the function from the required file into your functions.php?

Comment: @jdm2112 the second one *copy the function from the required file into your functions.php*

Comment: You should be good but obviously there's a problem.  I would test (temporarily) commenting out the parent's version to make sure your function works as expected.  If the parent version is truly still replacing your child version there is some other problem here.

Comment: @jdm2112 this is weird, I have commented the parent function as you told me and the behavior is the same as before meaning no changes, any ideas? (I am not using any cache plugin and theme hasn't cache options)

Comment: First thought is two possibilities (I'm sure there are more):  1. Child theme function is producing the same result as parent version.  or 2. Another section of code is responsible for the result you are looking to change, and these functions are not involved?  Hard to say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34608/discussion-between-jdm2112-and-reynierpm).

Comment: @jdm2112 I've found where the issue was and I have fixed but my solution is ugly so as soon as you can let me know and we can discuss this, thanks

Comment: Does your child theme contain a folder called `inc` and if so what does it contain?

Comment: @AntonChanning no, there is no such directory in the child theme

Comment: Are there any other mentions of `inc/alterna-functions.php` in the parent theme outside of the parent version of `functions.php`?

Comment: @AntonChanning nop, just that one

Comment: Are you doing this _after_ the `require_once`? If so, then your function will never happen.

Comment: @ReynierPM Would you like to post your solution as an answer? It's ok if it's not the best, just don't accept it yet - posting an answer will bump the entire question and some new people might be able to look into it for you, with your answer attempt as a base.

Comment: @TimMalone okie dokie, no problem I will keep this open for a while I am sure I will get a better solution from community

Comment: @ReynierPM is your question updated to reflect your working version? I would have guessed that the function is already defined by the parent theme therefore your opening if statement isn't working. Also php won't let you define the same function twice so at some point you're going to have to remove the definition from the parent theme, or ensure your child theme loads before your parent theme.

Comment: Please, always add updates as [edit]s to your question. Comments are meant to be cleaned up after the questions that arise here are incorporated.

Comment: The first question should be: »What theme do you use actually«?

Comment: @kaiser I've not working on this for a while, I don't even remember what I did change because I lose those changes with one update so I might be will not be helpful at all, sorry

Comment: You have it written in the comments…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new function in your child theme's functions.php cannot override a function from the parent's functions.php file unless that function is written to be pluggable, i.e. declared with `if (!function_exists('alterna_get_social_list'))`

Per the documentation on Child Themes and how they inherit from child functions.php files:

> **Using functions.php**
>   Unlike style.css, the functions.php of a child
>   theme does not override its counterpart from the parent. Instead, it
>   is loaded in addition to the parent’s functions.php. (Specifically, it
>   is loaded right before the parent’s file.)

[https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Using_functions.php][1]

Also, and this is super important:

> Do not copy the full content of functions.php of the parent theme into
>   functions.php in the child theme.

The only way to completely re-define a function that isn't pluggable is if it happens to be added via an action of some sort - then you can first remove the action calling the parent theme's function and add a new action that calls your new function with a different name.